# Select points inside shapes on Plotly JavaScript chart

Tags: javascript, plotly

Is it possible to draw a shape and select points within it on a plotly graph? I had thought of triggering a selection event using the coordinates of the points of the shapes, but I am struggling with this. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Thank you very much

Comment: If the goal is to select those points, you could just use `dragmode: 'lasso'`, @see this example https://plotly.com/javascript/lasso-selection/. Or you want to do it programatically ?

Comment: The goal is to to both thing, place some shapes and then select the point inside them, so I would like to do it programmatically

Comment: Using the same object for `shapes` and `selections`, I'm able to have the both element in the chart, but unfortunately the event `plotly_selected` is not fired, the selected points array is empty, and I can't find any way to trigger this event programmatically...